# when the page first renders it shows the whole list, then it checks and deletes the ones I subscribed to

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-usememo

I have a problem with react useMemo.

```
  const [cardlist, setCardList] = useState([]);
  const [subs, setSubs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCardList(); // for rendering cards on page first time 
  }, []);
  

  const uniqCard = useMemo(() => _.uniqBy(cardList, '_id'), [cardList]); // precaution for duplicate data

  const filteredCard = useMemo(() => uniqCard.filter((cardList) => !subs.includes(cardList._id)), [uniqCard, subs]); // i want to see cards which is i dont following, so i am filtering again card with subs(array of strings)
```

My problem is, when i refresh the page all list coming, then few seconds my functions, deleting cards which is following. But i dont want that.
I want when i refresh or open page, directly listing cards i don't follow.
Can u help for it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subs array is fed with async data, the initial value of `subs` is an empty array. The `filteredCard` is calculated as is, without filter (`!subs.includes` returns true), thus you have the unfiltered data that you don't want. You can keep a `loading` state and wait for `subs` so you can filter properly. Also, I don't think you need a `uniqCard` memo since it only utilizes a loadsh. You can merge these two memos.

Comment: Thanks bro. I put the loading on subs func and fixed.